# Unable to find local grunt File

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have a nodejs application which is build using azure devops. 
When i run the project i got below error.

> ```
> ##[debug]  --environment=test
> [command]C:\Users\ci-cd-admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt.cmd test_build --gruntfile C:\Users\ci-cd-admin\agent\_work\6\s\gruntfile.js --environment=test
> grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface (v1.3.2)
>
> Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.
>
> If you're seeing this message, grunt hasn't been installed locally to
> your project. For more information about installing and configuring grunt,
> please see the Getting Started guide:
>
> https://gruntjs.com/getting-started
> ##[debug]rc:99
> ##[debug]success:false
> ```

As you can see grunt-cli is installed and i will attach my package.json file below.

```
{
  "name": "vvvvvv",
  "version": "vv.vv.2",
  "description": "vvvv vvvvv vvvv",
  "homepage": "https://vvvv.vvvv.co",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://vvvv.vvvvv.com/_git/RMS"
  },
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENCE.md",
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd client && yarn start",
    "server": "nodemon ./server/server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn docs:build\" \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\"",
    "debug": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"nodemon --inspect=127.0.0.1:9229 server/server.js\" \"yarn client\"",
    "start": "sequelize db:migrate && sequelize db:seed:all && pm2 start server/server.js",
    "stop": "pm2 stop server/server.js",
    "docs:build": "documentation build server/** -f html -o client/public/server-doc && documentation build client/src/** -f html -o client/public/client-doc",
    "test": "mocha test --reporter mocha-junit-reporter --reporter-options mochaFile=./test-results.xml --exit",
    "report": "junit-viewer --results=test-results.xml --save=client/public/test-result.html",
    "migrate-dev": "sequelize db:migrate && sequelize db:seed:all --seeders-path server/seeders/common && sequelize db:seed:all --seeders-path server/seeders/test",
    "migrate-prod": "sequelize db:migrate && sequelize db:seed:all --seeders-path server/seeders/common && sequelize db:seed:all --seeders-path server/seeders/production",
    "sonar": "node sonar-project.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "assert-plus": "*",
    "body-parser": "1.18.3",
    "bunyan": "1.8.12",
    "client-credentials": "1.1.0",
    "concurrently": "4.1.0",
    "connect-mongo": "1.3.2",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.3",
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "ejs": ">= 0.0.0",
    "ejs-locals": ">= 0.0.0",
    "express": "4.16.4",
    "express-fileupload": "1.1.5",
    "express-handlebars": "3.0.2",
    "express-session": "1.14.1",
    "firebase-admin": "8.2.0",
    "graph-service": "2.1.3",
    "handlebars": "4.1.2",
    "helmet-csp": "^2.9.3",
    "json-rules-engine": "2.3.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.5.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.11",
    "method-override": "2.3.6",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "mongoose": "4.6.2",
    "morgan": "1.9.1",
    "nodejs-nodemailer-outlook": "1.1.0",
    "nodemailer": "6.1.0",
    "passport": "0.4.0",
    "passport-azure-ad": "4.1.0",
    "passport-jwt": "4.0.0",
    "pg": "7.8.1",
    "pg-hstore": "2.3.2",
    "sequelize": "4.43.0",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "1.10.3",
    "x-xss-protection": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.4",
    "@babel/node": "7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.4.4",
    "babel-cli": "6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "9.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "6.26.0",
    "chai": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "5.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "4.1.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "3.0.7",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.12.4",
    "grunt": "1.0.3",
    "grunt-clean": "0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "2.0.0",
    "grunt-env": "0.4.4",
    "grunt-shell": "3.0.1",
    "grunt-zip": "0.18.1",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "4.0.0",
    "mocha": "6.1.4",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "1.23.1",
    "prettier": "1.16.4",
    "sequelize-cli": "5.4.0",
    "sinon": "7.4.1",
    "sonarqube-scanner": "2.5.0",
    "supertest": "4.0.2"
  }
}
```

And my gruntfile.js is below.

```
/* eslint-disable global-require */
/* eslint-disable func-names */
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
  grunt.initConfig({
    env: {
      options: {},
      dev: {
        REACT_APP_ENV: grunt.option('environment') || 'production'
      }
    },
    shell: {
      build_server: {
        command: 'npm install'
      },
      build_client: {
        command: 'cd client && npm install && npm run build'
      }
    },
    clean: {
      folder: 'dist'
    },
    copy: {
      build: {
        files: [
          { src: 'server/**', dest: 'dist/' },
          { src: 'package.json', dest: 'dist/' },
          { src: '.sequelizerc', dest: 'dist/' },
          { src: 'client/build/**', dest: 'dist/' },
          { src: 'test/**', dest: 'dist/' },
        ]
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-clean');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-env');
  grunt.registerTask('prod_build', [
    'env',
    'shell:build_server',
    'shell:build_client',
    'clean',
    'copy:build'
  ]);
  grunt.registerTask('test_build', [
    'env',
    'shell:build_server',
    'shell:build_client',
    'clean',
    'copy:build'
  ]);
  grunt.registerTask('uat_build', [
    'env',
    'shell:build_server',
    'shell:build_client',
    'clean',
    'copy:build'
  ]);
  grunt.registerTask('regression_build', [
    'env',
    'shell:build_server',
    'shell:build_client',
    'clean',
    'copy:build'
  ]);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['shell:build_server', 'shell:build_client']);
};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like either Grunt hasn't been installed locally or you might be outside the project folder. You can try the following command from inside the project folder to install it to your dependencies,

'npm install bower --save-dev'